# How do I edit row in page 2 in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How do I Edit row in page 2 and on in gridview when i set pagesize in certain number(let's say pagesize="5") ?

It's possible to get value from certain row in page 1 of datagridview, but somehow when changed into page 2 it get nothing.

Back_user.aspx

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>"
                                        OnClick="linkEdit_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Assign task to this User ?');">Task</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Back_user.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub linkEdit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim btn As LinkButton = sender
        Dim idx As Integer = btn.CommandArgument

        idx = idx Mod 5

        Dim datarequest As String = datauser.Rows(idx).Cells(1).Text

        If datauser.Rows(idx).Cells(4).Text = "active" Or datauser.Rows(idx).Cells(4).Text = "pending" Then
            Session("IDRegis") = datarequest
            Response.Redirect("Back_UserAssign.aspx?Flag=EDIT")
        End If

    End Sub
```

```
Protected Sub OnPageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
        datauser.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    End Sub
```

So I want to make values is passed from page 2 and on in datagridview into another page same like page 1 ?
Well its a mess if i didn't use pagesize on this..

Thx, cheers

Comment: When you debug what is the value of idx when you edit from second page?

Comment: thx for the respond, idx get number based on row